# contentInset being ignored in ios7 for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

This worked before ios7 when someone tapped on anything that could become first responder inside a UIScrollView. Now it does not - UITextFields/Views still can show under the keyboard.

Code:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification{

//Some similar questions mentioned this might work, but made no difference for me
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

float height = 0.0;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
    height = kbSize.width;
} else {
    height = kbSize.height;
}

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, height, 0.0);


[UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                      delay:0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^
 {
     self.editorScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
     self.editorScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {

 }];
}
```

Currently, with this code nothing takes place when a uitextfield/view is assigned first responder status. The insets don't seem to change - I perhaps could use contentOffset but I would have to find the origin view's Y who just become first responder to do that.

Like I said, before ios7 this code worked (no textfield/view would be hidden behind the keyboard when assigned first responder status). I seem to be missing something obvious or perhaps there is a better way of doing this in ios7?

Comment: Can someone expand on why this is being down voted? I provided all the code for the applicable scenario and I would be happy to expand on anything if I a missing something obvious.

Comment: The comment on the "Close Vote" queue is its not clear what you are asking. They hunt in packs on stack overflow. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users.

Comment: I saw this in the queue and it seems above board to me. Not sure why its nominated for closing.

Comment: Ok, thanks...just wanted to make sure I was doing my part as far as asking the question goes.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about Objective-C or (Apple) IOS, but the question seems clear enough to me, and well-written enough. I'm also voting against closing. Perhaps one of the close-voters could post a comment specifying what they'd like to see clarified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to detect keyboard changing and frame.

The key point is to convert keyboard frame:   CGRect keyboardFrameInsideView = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardFrameWillChange:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];


- (void)keyboardFrameWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  CGRect keyboardFrame;
  [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];

  CGRect keyboardFrameInsideView = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];
  CGRect r = self.bodyView.frame;
  r.size.height = CGRectGetMinY(keyboardFrameInsideView) - r.origin.y;
  self.bodyView.frame = r;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, I will try this at work tomorrow and report back. If it works I will accept the answer

Comment: This is a different way. You are calling your way 'better' without explaining why. She / He is asking for the contentInsets and you don't even mention it.